# Shell command for getting history of a specific command

Tags: bash, command-line, command, back

I am looking for a command that shows what type of parameters are used earlier for the command I am using currently.

For example, if I want to use the command say `tail`, can I see the list of commands I have used recently which are of type `tail`. I know that command `history` gives recently used commands but I am looking for history of specific command. I am using bash shell.

Also if that is possible then can I restrict the result to see only 2 outputs that means recently used 2 `tail` commands?

Comment: in case you don't know, and if you press `CTRL+r` and keep typing `t` `a` .. bash will search in history what is the last command containing `ta`. But this offshoots your requirement

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would still use history. Just grep the command you like from the output of history:

```
history | grep tail
```

and only the two last ones:

```
history | grep tail | tail -3 | head -2
```

The tail -3 gives the last 3 in the list, but this includes the command you just typed in. So we then get the first two of the three to exclude the history line.